# How can i Get one contrller $scope value in another page

Tags: angularjs

Here i write simple angular Roution Like

```
 <li><a ui-sref="Login()">Login</a></li>
               <li><a ui-sref="Logout()" ng-show="!usersessionData">Logout</a></li>
```

**MyApp.js**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router'])

    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
                $stateProvider
     .state('Login', {
                    templateUrl: '/Kpmg/Homepages/LoginPages/Login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginCtrls'
                })
```

When i clik on Login its Redirect me 2 login page there when i submitted my credential successfully Logout should visuable.

**LoginCtrl.js**

```
$scope.usersessionData = false;
     $scope.SaveData = function (user) {
            var obj = { 'UserName': user.Email, 'password': user.psw, 'grant_type': 'password' }
            Login_Fac.GetLogin(obj).then(function (response) {
                User_Session.SetCurrentUser(response.data);
                $scope.usersessionData = true;
```

i need to controll  `<li><a ui-sref="Logout()" ng-show="!usersessionData">Logout</a></li>`  my logout by using usersessionData

Comment: A much cleaner approach than suggested would be to add a `Service` that holds the current userState and all its depending data. Then, all controllers that somehow need to access the current users state, just inject the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$rootScope.usersessionData = false;
$scope.SaveData = function (user) {
    var obj = { 'UserName': user.Email, 'password': user.psw, 'grant_type': 'password' }
        Login_Fac.GetLogin(obj).then(function (response) {
            User_Session.SetCurrentUser(response.data);
            $rootScope.usersessionData = true;
        }
}
```

and in your controller in which the saveData function is defined, inject $rootScope, for example:

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrls', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.usersessionData = false;
  $scope.saveData= ...;
});
```

Comment: Also add an ng-show to remove login button after user is logged in